# Setting an empty list of type object to a function that returns IEnumerable of type object

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

In my BLL I need to first declare an empty list and then eventually set it later in the code using a function from my DAL that returns type IEnumerable.

**Is this the proper way to do something like this?**

```
IEnumerable<productList> productList = new List<Product>();
productList = DAL.GetProducts();
```

Normally I just do the following, but the above scenario is different:

```
    IEnumerable<productList> productList = DAL.GeytProducts();
```

**Just to clear any confusion here is an example of my code:** I just want to know if I am doing this correctly:

```
IEnumerable<Product> retval = new List<Product>();

if (myInteger > 0) 
{
    retval = DAL.GetProducts1(); // this DAL function returns IEnumerable<Product>
} 
else 
{
    retval = DAL.GetProductHistory(); // this DAL function returns IEnumerable<Product>
}

return retval
```

Comment: You're creating and throwing a new instance of the list away.  It's pointless. Why do you think you have to do this?  This makes no sense.

Comment: @Will He said "eventually" set it later, which may mean it is accessed in the meantime and should be empty.  You don't know his application.

Comment: Not sure how I wouldn't have to do this... Lets say I need to declare an empty list on the outside of an if statement called RETVAL and then in the if else statement I need to set the list depending on the situation then finally return it at the end.

Comment: Your need is not clear - you want to create an empty list and then _fill_ it from your BLL?  Right now you're just replacing the reference with a reference to a _new_ list.  What's the purpose of the empty list?

Comment: Please see my update because I think there is a misunderstanding of what I am trying to do.

Comment: You are assigning a value in either branch of the if, so there's no reason to set it to anything initially.

Comment: Just initialise with null. no need to create a new list at the beginning

Comment: or you could even return from within the conditional branches unless your doing something else to the collection after the if/else

Comment: @jlew you're making as much an assumption as you accuse me of doing.  It's up to the OP to be *clear* when asking their questions, eh, OP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to create an empty list - just use

```
IEnumerable<Product> retval;
```

Your `if`/`else` will set the reference to the appropriate list from your DAL.

Creating an empty list is probably not hurting anything (since the list won't take up much memory and will be eligible for GC pretty quickly), but it's unnecessary.

You *could* also just do this

```
if (myInteger > 0) 
{
    return DAL.GetProducts1(); // this DAL function returns IEnumerable<Product>
} 
else 
{
    return DAL.GetProductHistory(); // this DAL function returns IEnumerable<Product>
}
```

or just

```
return myInteger > 0 ? DAL.GetProducts1() : DAL.GetProductHistory();
```

(assuming both return the same type)

and save yourself a variable, but it will not make any practical difference.

Comment: Thanks so much.. Sorry about this, my mindset was completely wrong. Should of thought to do this.. duh

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to instantiate the `retVal` as you are assigning it a value in `if` or `else` clause, it will eventually be assigned some value. So you can have:

```
IEnumerable<Product> retval;

if (myInteger > 0) 
{
    retval = DAL.GetProducts1(); // this DAL function returns IEnumerable<Product>
} 
else 
{
    retval = DAL.GetProductHistory(); // this DAL function returns IEnumerable<Product>
}

return retval;
```

or even you can return from `if` and else part directly like:

```
if (myInteger > 0) 
{
    return DAL.GetProducts1(); // this DAL function returns IEnumerable<Product>
} 
else 
{
    return DAL.GetProductHistory(); // this DAL function returns IEnumerable<Product>
}
```

But just make sure that all the code paths either return some value or set value to the `retVal`.